# Do TIE Fighters use minion rules?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, vehicles, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny, minion

A thing that currently confuses me is the stat block of the TIE pilot showing that they are normally are minions. But what about space fights? In space combat are they still used according to minion rules? Or do the TIEs each count as their own vehicle?

If the latter is the case, what does that mean for the TIE Fighter's pilot and gunnery skills — what value would they have?

Answer (score 7):

## TIEs are minions

AoR page 409, EotE page 389:

> Minions are typically not real threats when encountered alone…Minions will rarely be more than a minor obstacle to most parties of Player Characters, a delaying tactic that can stand in the way of achieving a goal that a more powerful enemy wishes to see prevented. Minions also tend to have lower wound thresholds than other NPCs, making it very likely that they'll drop in one or two hits.

That sounds like the definition of a TIE fighter.

- No real threat when encountered alone? Check
- A minor obstacle? Check
- Drop in one or two hits? Check

Also, they TIE pilot is specifically called out as a minion. The TIE doesn't change that; it is, after all, just another piece of equipment. Stormtroopers don't cease to be minions when you give them better weapons, and the same goes for TIE pilots.

Comment: That means in effect even normal vehicles can be used in accordance with the minion rules. interesting!

Comment: Even more explicitly, EotE page 283 has a sidebar for "Vehicles and Minions" that goes through how to use vehicles as minions and the rules for them.  I know there's a similar sidebar in AoR, but I don't have a reference in front of me.